# Selenium not able to locate element in browser DOM

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a tests suite where I **must** have to use css selectors.

When I make a query through selenium

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#credentials.errors"));
```

OR

```
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
      ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.
        getElementById('credentials.errors');");
    }
```

OR

If I search for `#credentials.errors` manually in browser csspath query

It's simply not able to locate element but
I can locate that element in browser console by making query

```
document.getElementById('credentials.errors')
```

**My question is if element can located by JavaScript console then why not by selenium webdriver?**

Comment: Try to use explicit wait until selenium webdrive finds element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `#credentials.errors` looks for an element with the ID "credentials" and a class "errors", *not* an element with the ID "credentials.errors". The dot is being interpreted as the start of a class selector. In other words, it's equivalent to `.errors#credentials`, with both simple selectors swapped around.

`document.getElementById()` works because it simply takes a string as the input ID. It does not try to parse it as a compound selector.

To correctly locate the element with an ID selector, you need to escape the dot:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#credentials\\.errors"));
```

You can also use an attribute selector instead so you don't have to escape anything:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id='credentials.errors']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the element created by client side script after Ajax calling, so you need to wait using WebDriverWait

Comment: Yes, it's Ajax but i can't even manually able to search it in css query path. But, in js console it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an ID to find the element you could use the following instead of using the By.cssSelector:

```
driver.findElement(By.Id("credentials.errors"));
```